# Group json object into 1 groupping commond values

Tags: javascript, json

Hello I would like to group two json objects on one grouping the commond values on a single array tag.

I have this input:

```js
const json = {
   "2280492":[
      {
         "ID":"2280492",
         "Name":"Paula Luying",
         "Surname":"Domingo",
         "Estate":"End",
         "Date_End":"4/15/2021 12:31",
         "Date_final":"4/22/2021 13:57",
         "Time":"7 days 1 hours",
         "Note":"7.83"
      },
      {
         "ID":"2280492",
         "Name":"Paula Luying",
         "Surname":"Domingo",
         "Estate":"End",
         "Date_End":"4/22/2021 13:58",
         "Date_final":"4/23/2021 11:36",
         "Time":"21 hours 38 minutes",
         "Note":"0"
      }
   ],
   "2423536":[
      {
         "ID":"2423536",
         "Name":"Josep",
         "Surname":"Mora",
         "Estate":"Acabat",
         "Date_End":"4/19/2021 10:31",
         "Date_final":"4/19/2021 11:19",
         "Time":"48 minutes 33 seconds",
         "Note":"9"
      },
      {
         "ID":"2423536",
         "Name":"Josep",
         "Surname":"Mora",
         "Estate":"Acabat",
         "Date_End":"4/19/2021 11:20",
         "Date_final":"4/22/2021 22:43",
         "Time":"3 days 11 hours",
         "Note":"4.67"
      }
   ]
}
```

And I want to have something like this for output, as you can see the commond tag like "ID", "NAME, "Surname" are grouppeds and there is another tag call activities with the uncommond data:

```js
const json = [
   {
      "ID":"2280492",
      "Name":"Paula Luying",
      "Surname":"Domingo",
      "Activities":[
         {
            "Estate":"End",
            "Date_End":"4/15/2021 12:31",
            "Date_final":"4/22/2021 13:57",
            "Time":"7 days 1 hours",
            "Note":"7.83"
         },
         {
            "Estate":"End",
            "Date_End":"4/22/2021 13:58",
            "Date_final":"4/23/2021 11:36",
            "Time":"21 hours 38 minutes",
            "Note":"0"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "ID":"2423536",
      "Name":"Josep",
      "Surname":"Mora",
      "Activities":[
         {
            "Estate":"Acabat",
            "Date_End":"4/19/2021 10:31",
            "Date_final":"4/19/2021 11:19",
            "Time":"48 minutes 33 seconds",
            "Note":"9"
         },
         {
            "Date_End":"4/19/2021 11:20",
            "Date_final":"4/22/2021 22:43",
            "Time":"3 days 11 hours",
            "Note":"4.67"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Did you attempt to solve this yourself?  Show the code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it

```js
const groupByIdNameSurname = (data) => Object.values(data.reduce((res, {
  ID,
  Name,
  Surname,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const Activities = res[ID]?.Activities || []
  res[ID] = {
    ID,
    Name,
    Surname,
    Activities: [...Activities, rest]
  }
  return res
}, {}))


const json = {
  "2280492": [{
      "ID": "2280492",
      "Name": "Paula Luying",
      "Surname": "Domingo",
      "Estate": "End",
      "Date_End": "4/15/2021 12:31",
      "Date_final": "4/22/2021 13:57",
      "Time": "7 days 1 hours",
      "Note": "7.83",
    },
    {
      "ID": "2280492",
      "Name": "Paula Luying",
      "Surname": "Domingo",
      "Estate": "End",
      "Date_End": "4/22/2021 13:58",
      "Date_final": "4/23/2021 11:36",
      "Time": "21 hours 38 minutes",
      "Note": "0",
    }
  ],
  "2423536": [{
      "ID": "2423536",
      "Name": "Josep",
      "Surname": "Mora",
      "Estate": "Acabat",
      "Date_End": "4/19/2021 10:31",
      "Date_final": "4/19/2021 11:19",
      "Time": "48 minutes 33 seconds",
      "Note": "9",
    },
    {
      "ID": "2423536",
      "Name": "Josep",
      "Surname": "Mora",
      "Estate": "Acabat",
      "Date_End": "4/19/2021 11:20",
      "Date_final": "4/22/2021 22:43",
      "Time": "3 days 11 hours",
      "Note": "4.67",
    }
  ]
}

console.log(groupByIdNameSurname(Object.values(json).flat()))
```